# Why do goroutines solve deadlock issues with buffered channels?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a buffered channel which I purposely limit to 2 elements. When I write more elements to the channel without reading from it, I get a deadlock as expected. However if I use a goroutine to do write to my channel, the issue is gone. Why?

```
// Function to process messages in an array. We stop processing once we
// encounter the string 'stop' even if there are other messages
func processCmd(s []string, c chan int) {

    msgCount := 0

    for index, v := range s {

        if index == len(s)-1 && v == "stop" {
            // If we've reached the last element and the message is "stop", don't count it
            break
        } else if v == "stop" {
            c <- msgCount // Send msgCount to the channel
            continue
        } else {
            msgCount++
        }
    }

    c <- msgCount // Send msgCount to the channel

    close(c)
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"message a", "message b", "message c", "stop", "message d", "stop", "message e"}

    c := make(chan int, 2)

    processCmd(s, c)
    //go processCmd(s, c) // doesn't have an issue with buffer length

    for v := range c {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When running `processCmd` inline (as shown in the code), there is nothing to receive from the channel. Once two elements have been added, `processCmd` will just wait until there is room to add more. As you said, this works as expected.

When running `processCmd` in a goroutine, `main()` launches the goroutine and enters the `for v := range c` loop. This will consume items from `c` until the channel is closed. As soon as `v := range c` consumes the first element, `processCmd` is free to add more data to the channel, unblocking it.

This will continue until `processCmd` closes the channel, at which point the for loop will terminate as will the program.

Note: for visibility, don't forget to add the `go` label. Not many people watch the `goroutine` label.